# Toggle button JS changing value in LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a favourite button next to a list which a person can toggle on and off whenever he wants and store a value inside the localstorage so it will be saved on refresh. How would I create a button which when clicked it will turn yellow and update the localstorage to "favourite": True, and if pressed again the button will turn back to default and update local storage to "favourite": False. Thanks

```
function favourite(element) {

    var allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));

    if (allPlaces.favourite == true) {
        allPlaces.favourite = false;
        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star-outline');
    } else {
        allPlaces.favourite = true;
        element.style.color = '#FFE234';
        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star');
    }
    localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(allPlaces));
}
```

**These are the objects inside the Local Storage (LS)**

"title": title,
"description": description,
"category": category,
"favourite": false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should conditionally render the button based on the favourite prop,
so when favourite have to change you should set the new value in tha localStorage

First retrieve the object with JSON.parse

```
let place = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myPlaces'))
```

and then change directly the "favourite" prop

```
let newValue = {
...place,
favourite: false}
```

and store the new object in the localStorage:

```
const newPlaceStringified = JSON.stringify(newValue)
localStorage.setItem('myPlaces', newPlaceStringified )
```

So the next time your favourite is saved correctly and can render conditionally the button and the logic

```
function favourite(element) {

    var allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));

    if (allPlaces["favourite"] == true) {
        
        localStorage.setItem(
                      'myItem',
                      JSON.stringify({
                        ...item1,
                        favourite: false,
                       }),
       )
    
        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star-outline');

    } else {
            localStorage.setItem(
              'myItem',
              JSON.stringify({
                ...item1,
              favourite: true,
               }),
            )

        element.style.color = '#FFE234';
        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star');
    }
    

    
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you are saying to be honest. Could you try to be a bit more clear pls? Thanks much appreciated.

Comment: No problem I updated the function with what I was meaning, I think the problem here is that when you write " newPlaces.favourite = false or true " you are not saving this value anywhere so in the next render of that function the allPlaces didnt change at all, so you should refresh localStorage with the new value, I hope this works!!!

Comment: Would there be a way to overwrite the current object rather than creating a new one?

Comment: In this case you have to call localStorage two times, or shortly in the other method just dont use modifiedString and update localStorage directly with JSON.stringify, I finished now to change it

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
window.onload = function () {
  const btn = document.getElementById("button");
  const allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));

  if (allPlaces && allPlaces.favourite) {
    btn.style.color = "#FFE234";
  } else {
    btn.style.color = "#000000";
  }
};

function favourite(element) {
  var allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces")) || {};

  if (allPlaces.favourite === true) {
    allPlaces.favourite = false;
    document.querySelector("ion-icon").setAttribute("name", "star-outline");
    element.style.color = "#000000";
  } else {
    allPlaces.favourite = true;
    element.style.color = "#FFE234";
    document.querySelector("ion-icon").setAttribute("name", "star");
  }
  localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(allPlaces));
}
```

```
<button id='button' onclick="favourite(this)">Fav</button>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it's not working. I already have a button with an onclick all I need is some way to set favourite to false or true, just like in the favourite function.